# Regex with at least three even digits and odd length

Tags: regular-expressions

As the title said, I need to make a regex for a number with at least three even digits and odd length.
As an example, the number 248 should match.
Thank you!

Comment: How about the number $21418$?

Comment: yes, this should match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e$ denote any even digit and $o$ any odd digit. Let

$$E=\big((e+o)(e+o)\big)^*$$

and

$$O=(e+o)E\,.$$

Then the expression

$$\begin{align*}
&E(eee+eeEe+eEee+eEeEe+eOeOe)E\\
&\qquad+O(eee+eeEe+eEee+eEeEe+eOeOe)O\\
&\qquad+E(eeOe+eOee+eOeEe+eEeOe)O\\
&\qquad+O(eeOe+eOee+eOeEe+eEeOe)E
\end{align*}$$

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to create capturing and non-capturing groups (e.g. python) then it is possible to reduce the regex by having an AND operation performed rather than having to list all combinations like in Brian's answer.

```
(?=oddcount)(?:evendigits)

oddcount = ^[0-9]([0-9][0-9])+$

evendigits = ^[0-9]*[02468][0-9]*[02468][0-9]*[02468][0-9]*$
```

Note: *I enclosed expression inside `^...$` to match the whole string, not just some part of it.*

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/dgbngY/1